# Node.js updating session field

Tags: javascript, node.js

In my `req.session.cart` I have numbers of object. I want to update the quantity field whenever the particular is passed as query parameter. I tried but I'm only able to append another quantity field instead of updating it.

```
[
  { 
    "_id": "573e8cb8d41066b112908598",
    "quantity": 1
  },
  {
    "_id": "573e8c6ad41066b112908597",

    "quantity": 1
  }
]
```

this is what I tried

```
function processEdit(req, res, next) {
    var quantity = req.body.quantity;
    req.session.cart.forEach(function(data) {
        if (data._id == req.params._id) {
            arrayTrue = false;
        }
    });
    if (arrayTrue) {
        req.session.cart.quantity = quantity;
        console.log(req.session.cart);
    }
    res.send(req.session.cart);
```

Comment: where is your updating code?

Comment: @vp_arth I have updated what I tried

Comment: `req.session.cart[index].quantity` - Your cart is array

Comment: @vp_arth yes got it, but here index can be anything

Comment: you can save index from second argument of your `forEach` above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your cart is an array.

`req.session.cart[index].quantity++` if you have an index.

And if you have an id:

```
req.session.cart.forEach(item => {
  if (item._id == id) {
     item.quantity++;
  }
});
```